# About the integral $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\ln\left(\frac{\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\ln\left(x^{2}-x+\frac{17}{4}\right)}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$$I=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\ln\left(\frac{\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\ln\left(x^{2}-x+\frac{17}{4}\right)}\right)dx$$
Using CAS the answer comes out to be:
$$I=-\frac{3}{2}\ln(2)$$

For the Indefinite Integral, Wolfram says it has no solution in terms of standard mathematical functions.

The limits of the Definite Integral do give out the hint of replacing $x \to \frac{1}{x}$, but after trying it, I do not end up with a solvable Integral either.
$$I=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\ln\left(\frac{\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{17}{4}\right)}\right)\frac{1}{x^{2}}dx$$

Adding these two integrals which usually helps does not resolve the problem here either.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: @BrunoB Apologies, I did not know.

Comment: Did you obtain the result or did you identify what is $-1.03972$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Got 16 digits using Wolfram, then used Inverse Symbolic Calculator Integer Relation Algorithms

Comment: This is what I supposed. Do you know what : a series solution works !

Comment: I think that you should tell it in the post. Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I do have some reason to believe it can be done without series solution.

Comment: I could have sworn there was a question on this site exactly like this one!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A question from Integration Bee 2022: Evaluate $\int^2_{1/2}\ln(\frac{\ln(x+\frac{1}{x})}{\ln(x^2-x+\frac{17}{4})})dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504838/a-question-from-integration-bee-2022-evaluate-int2-1-2-ln-frac-lnx-fra)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int_\frac12^2\ln\left(\frac{\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\ln\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+4\right)}\right)dx=\int_\frac12^2\ln\left(\frac{\color{magenta}{2}\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\color{magenta}2\ln\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+4\right)}\right)dx$$

$$=-\ln 2 \underbrace{\int_\frac12^2 dx}_{=\frac32}+\underbrace{\int_\frac12^2\ln\left(\frac{\color{red}{\ln\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2\right)}}{\color{blue}{\ln\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+4\right)}}\right)dx}_{=0}=-\frac32\ln 2$$

---

In order to show that the second integral vanishes, we can split the logarithm in two parts.

$$\int_\frac12^2\ln\left(\color{red}{\ln\left(\left(x+\frac1x\right)^2\right)}\right)dx=\int_\frac12^1+\int_1^2\overset{x+\frac1x\to x}=\int_2^\frac52\frac{x\ln(\ln(x^2))}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}dx$$

$$\overset{x^2-4\to x^2}=\int_0^\frac32\ln(\ln(x^2+4))dx\overset{x\to x-\frac12}=\int_\frac12^2\ln\left(\color{blue}{\ln\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+4\right)}\right)dx$$

Answer (score 10):

Note$$I=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\ln\frac{\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\ln\left(x^{2}-x+\frac{17}{4}\right)}dx=I_2-I_1$$
where

\begin{align}
 I_1=&\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\ln \ln\left(x^2-x+\frac{17}4\right)\overset{y=x-\frac12}{dx}
=\int_{0}^{\frac32}\ln \ln\left(
y^2+4\right)dy\\
\\
I_2=&\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\ln \ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\overset{x\to\frac1x}{dx}\\
=& \ \frac12\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\ln \ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right) \overset{y=x-\frac1x}{dx}\\
=& \ \frac12\int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^{\frac32}\ln \left(\frac12\ln\left(y^2+4\right)\right)dy
= \int_{0}^{\frac32}\ln \left(\frac12\ln\left(y^2+4\right)\right)dy\\
\end{align}
Thus
$$I=\int_0^{\frac32}\ln\frac12=-\frac32\ln2$$

Comment: Not surprizing : very nice ! Thanks